# invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 21)

Tags: python

I get this error message when I try to debug I don't know whats wrong
this is auto Reddit poster

line 21  is     except Exception, e:

this line of code seems fine I don't know why I'm getting an error.

```
import praw
import json
import urllib

import settingslocal

REDDIT_USERNAME = ''
REDDIT_PASSWORD = ''

try:
    from settingslocal import *
except ImportError:
    pass

def main():
    print ('starting')

    url = "http://api.ihackernews.com/page"
    try:
        result = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    except Exception, e:
    return

    items = result['items'][:-1]

    reddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent='HackerNews bot by /u/mpdavis')
    reddit.login(REDDIT_USERNAME, REDDIT_PASSWORD)
    link_submitted = False
    for link in items:
        if link_submitted:
            return
        try:
            #Check to make sure the post is a link and not a post to another HN page. 
            if not 'item?id=' in link['url'] and not '/comments/' in link['url']:
                submission = list(reddit.get_info(url=str(link['url'])))
                if not submission:
                    subreddit = get_subreddit(str(link['title']))
                    print "Submitting link to %s: %s" % (subreddit, link['url'])
                    resp = reddit.submit(subreddit, str(link['title']), url=str(link['url']))
                    link_submitted = True

        except Exception, e:
            print e
            pass
```

Comment: Post whole error message with traceback please.

Comment: Which line is your "line 21"? Also there are indent errors in your code.

Comment: Could you please provide [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running Python 3. If so, these lines have two problems:

```
try:
    result = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
except Exception, e:
return
```

1. `except Exception, e:` syntax is Python 2 only; the Python 3 equivalent is `except Exception as e:`
2. Your `return` isn't indented, the contents of the `except` block must be indented.

The fixed code would be:

```
try:
    result = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
except Exception as e:
    return
```

or just:

```
try:
    result = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
except Exception:
    return
```

which doesn't bother to capture the exception as `e` since you never use it.

Similarly, further on down, you'd need to change:

```
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

to:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

to run on Python 3. You might just want to use [the `2to3` tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) to perform these changes (and any other 2/3 related changes I missed) automatically, or just install Python 2.7 to run this script unmodified (though Python 2 goes out of support completely at the beginning of next year, so that's not a long term solution).

Comment: I have done the things you said but now I get another syntax error on line 38

code:    

print "Submitting link to %s: %s" % (subreddit, link['url'])

Comment: @Sassy: Yeah, all the `print`s need to add parentheses (it's no longer a reserved keyword with special syntax, just a regular built-in function). Frankly, you should probably revert to the original code and just run the `2to3` converter with `2to3 -w nameofscript.py` to perform all the corrections at once, automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your line 21 is

```
except Exception, e:
return
```

for which there are two problems:

1. `except` is in wrong syntax.  I am clueless on what you are trying to do.  Please refer to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html for correct syntax.  I suspect you were trying to write `except Exception as e:` ?
2. the block after the `except` is not correct indented.